# ERROR using OutputFcn - VarargoutNotCell

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

i have a mat file and a gui running smoothly on matlab command window but when i compiled it it shows an error saying:

```
??? Error using ==> charms_OutputFcn
variable output array 'varargout' must be a cell array.
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn 248
Error in ==> charms at 40

MATLAB:VarargoutNotCell
Warning:1 visible figure(s) exist at MCR termination
```

my line 40 is like this:

```
  [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

how can i resolve this , thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
varargout = cell(1,nargout);
[varargout{:}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

I think that the Matlab function `deal` is the prototype example for this kind of operation.  `edit deal` to see how the Mathworks did it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the surrounding `{}` should be removed: I'm surprised it even runs!

Second, you need to initialise `varargout` to be a cell array of the correct size using the `cell` command.

Comment: sorry for the wrong post, actually it doesnt have a surrounding `{}` i have edited the post. how can i initialize it for the correct size array can you give an example . thanks for the response